# How similar are Ecoque grills to Pyromid grills?

Tags: gear, cooking, grilling

I purchased a [Pyromid grill](http://www.kifaruforums.net/showthread.php?t=10667&p=116870#post116870) at a garage sale without a manual, and have an [Ecoque grill](http://www.ecoque.com/portable-grills) manual. I would like to know if I need to do anything different from the Ecoque instructions to operate the Pyromid grill. Unfortunately, Pyromid is out of business, so I cannot ask them anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe that Ecoque is the Pyromid resurrected.  I found this in my search for new liners: http://www.backwoodshome.com/blogs/ClaireWolfe/2012/06/05/pyromid-is-back/ The liners are on Amazon for U$7.99 per dozen. (the stoves run over U$100)  I can't get thru to the Ecoque website at work (filtering.....), but they do have one: www.ecoque.com

I haven't used mine in over 10 years, so I'm rusty.  But, unfold the base, set it on a sturdy surface, unfold the ash collector set it on the base, unfold the upper shield, set it into the ash collector, unfold the foil and place in the upper shield (the foil can reduce cooking time by 25%), set in the lower tray, set in the upper tray place the charcoal on it's edges in the slots, light the charcoal (there were fuel pellets, Esbit?) to start the charcoal.  Place the grill over the charcoal, unfold the cover and place it over the grill for direct heat baking.  There were smoking and baking hood available, not sure if they're still around.

Answer (score 3):

I have both a 12" original Pyromid and the new Ecoque grill in 12". The pieces are all quite similar and interchangeable. The new model works as well as the original. both are fantastic little grills capable of high heat output.